# "kiru" used to refer to a card?

Tags: word-choice, words, expressions, anime

In Bungou Stray Dogs S2E07, the enemy pulled off something really abhorrent, and in response, Dazai says "敵｛てき｝がその気｛き｝なら、こちらも鬼札｛おにふだ｝を切｛き｝ろう". I can understand that [onifuda](https://jisho.org/search/onifuda) is like "wildcard" (literally, "demon card"). But I don't understand the usage of "kiru" here. Is "kiru" a word that's often used with cards? I could understand 出す or 使う, but I've never heard 切る used with regards to a card. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, (カードを)切る is a verb commonly used in card gaming contexts, and it has several meanings depending on the context:

1. "to shuffle", specifically with [the 'Hindu shuffle' move](https://youtu.be/ylifviUQHrI?si=HU_K_s-NEy__aQNR) (I didn't know this name, but this is the most basic shuffling method children learn in Japan)
2. "to use/play" (an important card to win or change the momentum of the game)
3. "to discard/sacrifice" (a less important card or piece in games such as poker, mahjong, chess, etc)

In your case, it's 2. You can also use 出す and 使う, but 札 and 切る are words that are commonly collocated. [切り札](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E5%88%87%E3%82%8A%E6%9C%AD) is a common phrase used even outside gaming contexts.

Comment: I was aware of the shuffling one (1.) and kirifuda, but didn't know of (2.) at all. I'm surprised it never once came up in 200+ episodes of YuGiOh @.@. I'd imagine it's an especially specialized (or antiquated) term... And as for (3.), I've only heard "suteru", but I'm assuming you're right.

Comment: @chausies Indeed, (2) is no longer common in actual card games. It's not antiquated, but is now mainly used metaphorically in the context of political, litigation or war tactics (e.g., 切れる手札は限られている meaning there are not many options to choose).